# Remove specific array from multiple array set using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I have two checkboxes. When I check one, the code will get status and id of that checkbox and push into array, if that value is not present already

The array set become like this

```
  [8,0] [10,0]
```

Requirements:

1. It is inserting [8,0] [8,0] twice if I check and then uncheck and again check it so this should not insert multiple times same values
2. Remove specific array from set of array so if I uncheck chkecbox then remove only [8,0] but keep  [10,0]

```js
var positions = [];

$("body").on('click', '.check_box', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var status = $(this).attr('data-status');
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) { // if click on check
    if (!$.inArray(id, positions)) positions.push(id); // if id and status not in array then only push
    positions.push([id, status]); //  it will  insert  like [8,10] but geting duplicate  [8,10] [8,10]
    console.log(positions);
  } else {
    // if uncheck checkbox

    //  remove specific  value like  [8,0] or if value present [10,0] then remove this
    console.log(positions);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" data-id="8" data-status="0">

<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" data-id="10" data-status="0">
```

Comment: YOu need to check to index while removing value in array you can use `splice` `https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp`

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: @jishansiddique i tried that also but it is not removing single set like [8,0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to check if object is present in array & add only if it doesn't exist

For removing, you can use `filter` & select only those objects in array which are not exactly as you specify

```js
var positions = [];

$("body").on('click', '.check_box', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var status = $(this).attr('data-status');
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    var exists = false;
    positions.forEach((p) => {
      if (id == p[0] && status == p[1]);
        exists = true;
    });
    if (!exists) {
      positions.push([id, status]);
    }  
  } else {
    positions = positions.filter(function(a) {
      return !(a[0] == id && a[1] == status);
    });
  }
  console.log(positions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" data-id="8" data-status="0">

<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" data-id="10" data-status="0">
```

> Explanation

1. In The first loop `.each` we iterate through each existing values in array & set `exist` to true when we find an element which has id & status same as the one we selected

   - If after loop we have exist as true, we know it already exists & we won't push it to array, otherwise we will push it to the array
2. In else condition we have used `filter` function of array, this fuction filters the array & only keep the elements for which we returned true, for elements we return false, it gets removed from resulting array

   - So we did check every element of array for exact match of `id` & `status` & if its matched we return false, so it gets removed from the resulting array

Comment: it is not working same values inserting again and again

Comment: I want o insert that value when checked and if I unchecked that checkbox value related with  checkbox should be remove

Comment: @mplungjan I tried with if(positions.indexOf([id,status])===-1) but this also not preventing from pushing duplicate values

Comment: I just updated the code, please run it & check again

Comment: thanks a lot you saved my time I was working on it  last one  hour , can you please please explain about loop concept and your code ,just little bit

Comment: Great exercise. However if only a few checkboxes, my solution is MUCH simpler

Comment: @msp I have added more explanation in the answer, check it out

Answer (score 2):

I will use **findIndex** and **splice** to handle it, hope this can help you :)

```js
$(function() {
    let positions = [];
    $("body").on('click', 'input:checkbox', function() {
        let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        let status = $(this).attr('data-status');
        let data = [id, status];
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            positions.push(data);
        } else {
            let index = positions.findIndex(c => c[0] === id);
            if (index != -1)
                positions.splice(index, 1);
        }
        $('#result').html(positions.toString());
    });
});
```

```css
#result{
  width: 20rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:dashed;
  border-color:#FFAC55;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="A" data-status="0">A</button>
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="B" data-status="0">B</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is small, just recreate it each time

```js
let positions;
$("body").on('click', '.check_box', function() {
  positions = [];
  $(".check_box:checked").each(function() {
    positions.push([
     $(this).data('id'), $(this).data('status')
   ]);
  });
  console.log(positions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" data-id="8" data-status="0">

<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" data-id="10" data-status="0">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and your valuable time. I will consider this also